# Android runtime permissions- how to implement

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

[Android Developer Documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) gives this example of requesting permissions at runtime:

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

        // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
}
```

What is "MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS" in this example? It says it's an app-defined int constant, but does that mean I should make a Constants.java and declare a public static int? What should the value be?

In other examples I see people use 1 here, or 0 or 0xFFEEDDCC, but I can't find an explanation of what it is. Can someone explain to me what needs to go here and why? (In my case, I need to make sure the app has permission to access fine location)

The ActivityCompat documentation says "Application specific request code to match with a result reported to onRequestPermissionsResult"? This does not help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android permissions - Manifest or android.manifest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34901870/android-permissions-manifest-or-android-manifest)

Comment: You can check a class that I've created and use it in Fragments github.com/mptrista/PermissionHelper It is for fragments and in the case for requesting a single permission.

Comment: Implement `runtime permissions` (If user choose don't ask me again then open `Setting` for permission) detailed = https://stackoverflow.com/a/52713829/12750160

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> What is "MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS" in this example?

It is an `int`, to tie a particular `requestPermissions()` call to the corresponding `onRequestPermissionsResult()` callback.

Under the covers, `requestPermissions()` uses `startActivityForResult()`; this `int` serves the same role as it does in `startActivityForResult()`.

> does that mean I should make a Constants.java and declare a public static int?

I would just make it a `private static final int` in the activity. But, you can declare it wherever you want.

> What should the value be?

I seem to recall that it needs to be below 0x8000000, but otherwise it can be whatever you want. The value that you use for each `requestPermissions()` call in an activity should get a distinct `int`, but the actual numbers do not matter.

If your activity has only one `requestPermissions()` call, then the `int` value really does not matter. But many apps will have several `requestPermissions()` calls in an activity. In that case, the developer may need to know, in `onRequestPermissionsResult()`, what request this is the result for.

Answer (score 3):

Look just a little further down in the documentation under "Handle the permissions request response" and you will see its purpose.

A callback method called `onRequestPermissionsResult` gets sent back the same code as a parameter so you know which permission was being requested/granted:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

Since the constant is used by you only you can give it whatever value you like as a `public static final int`. Each permission being requested needs its own constant.

Answer (score 3):

I went through all answers, but doesn't satisfied my exact needed answer, so here is an example that I wrote and perfectly works, even user clicks the *Don't ask again* checkbox.

1. Create a method that will be called when you want to ask for runtime permission like `readContacts()` or you can also have `openCamera()` as shown below:

   ```
   private void readContacts() {
       if (!askContactsPermission()) {
           return;
       } else {
           queryContacts();
       } }
   ```

Now we need to make `askContactsPermission()`, you can also name it as `askCameraPermission()` or whatever permission you are going to ask.

```
    private boolean askContactsPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        return true;
    }
    if (checkSelfPermission(READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    }
    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(READ_CONTACTS)) {
        Snackbar.make(parentLayout, R.string.permission_rationale, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction(android.R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
                    }
                }).show();
    } else if (contactPermissionNotGiven) {
        openPermissionSettingDialog();
    } else {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
        contactPermissionNotGiven = true;

    }
    return false;
}
```

Before writing this function make sure you have defined the below instance variable as shown:

```
    private View parentLayout;
    private boolean contactPermissionNotGiven;;


/**
 * Id to identity READ_CONTACTS permission request.
 */
private static final int REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 0;
```

Now final step to override the `onRequestPermissionsResult` method as shown below:

```
/**
 * Callback received when a permissions request has been completed.
 */
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
        if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            queryContacts();
        }
    }
}
```

Here we are done with the RunTime permissions, the addon is the `openPermissionSettingDialog()` which simply open the Setting screen if user have permanently disable the permission by clicking *Don't ask again* checkbox. below is the method:

```
    private void openPermissionSettingDialog() {
    String message = getString(R.string.message_permission_disabled);
    AlertDialog alertDialog =
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT)
                    .setMessage(message)
                    .setPositiveButton(getString(android.R.string.ok),
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                                    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                    Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                                    intent.setData(uri);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            }).show();
    alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
}
```

What we missed ?
1. Defining the used strings in `strings.xml`

```
<string name="permission_rationale">"Contacts permissions are needed to display Contacts."</string>
    <string name="message_permission_disabled">You have disabled the permissions permanently,
        To enable the permissions please go to Settings -> Permissions and enable the required Permissions,
        pressing OK you will be navigated to Settings screen</string>
```

2. Initializing the `parentLayout` variable inside `onCreate` method

   parentLayout = findViewById(R.id.content);
3. Defining the required permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

4. The `queryContacts` method, based on your need or the runtime permission you can call your method before which the `permission` was needed. in my case I simply use the loader to fetch the contact as shown below:

   ```
   private void queryContacts() {
   getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);}
   ```

This works great happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SplashActivity extends RuntimePermissionsActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    SplashActivity.super.requestAppPermissions(new
                    String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, R.string.app_name
            , 20);

}

@Override
public void onPermissionsGranted(int requestCode) {


    try {
        TelephonyManager tele = (TelephonyManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        String imei =tele.getDeviceId()
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public abstract class RuntimePermissionsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private SparseIntArray mErrorString;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mErrorString = new SparseIntArray();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    int permissionCheck = PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    for (int permission : grantResults) {
        permissionCheck = permissionCheck + permission;
    }
    if ((grantResults.length > 0) && permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        onPermissionsGranted(requestCode);
    } else {

        finish();

    }
}

public void requestAppPermissions(final String[] requestedPermissions,
                                  final int stringId, final int requestCode) {
    mErrorString.put(requestCode, stringId);
    int permissionCheck = PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    boolean shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale = false;
    for (String permission : requestedPermissions) {
        permissionCheck = permissionCheck + ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
        shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale = shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, permission);
    }
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(RuntimePermissionsActivity.this, requestedPermissions, requestCode);
            /*Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), stringId,
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("GRANT",
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(RuntimePermissionsActivity.this, requestedPermissions, requestCode);
                        }
                    }).show();*/
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, requestedPermissions, requestCode);
        }
    } else {
        onPermissionsGranted(requestCode);
    }
}

public abstract void onPermissionsGranted(int requestCode);
```

}