# Unable to retrieve SMS display name

Tags: android, sms, android-contacts

I've been trying to retrieve SMS information but have only been to retrieve everything BUT the display name of contacts. `strDisplayName`only shows the numerical value of a particular contact and not the name itself. All other string version of data shows their corresponding information correctly *(aside from "date")*. **I've tried other implementations of getting the display name from other answers, but doing so causes the app to crash when trying to test.**

```
    Uri smsData = Uri.parse("content://sms/" + folderName);
    String[] id = new String[]
            {
                    "_id", "person", "address",
                    "body", "date"
            };

    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor smsCursor = contentResolver.query(smsData, null, null, null, null);

    // Retrieve index of data
    int indexContactID = smsCursor.getColumnIndex(id[0]);
    int indexDisplayName = smsCursor.getColumnIndex(id[1]);
    int indexPhoneNumber = smsCursor.getColumnIndex(id[2]);
    int indexMsg = smsCursor.getColumnIndex(id[3]);
    int indexDate = smsCursor.getColumnIndex(id[4]);

    if (indexMsg < 0 || !smsCursor.moveToFirst())
        return;

    mCustomAdapter.clear();

    while (smsCursor.moveToNext())
    {
        // Retrieve string version of data
        String strContactID = smsCursor.getString(indexContactID);
        String strDisplayName = smsCursor.getString(indexDisplayName);
        String strContactNumber = smsCursor.getString(indexPhoneNumber);
        String strMsg = smsCursor.getString(indexMsg);
        String strDate = smsCursor.getString(indexDate);

        String[] textMessage = new String[]
        {
                strContactID, strDisplayName, strContactNumber,
                strMsg, strDate
        };

        // Place collected data into custom adapter
        mCustomAdapter.add(textMessage);
    }
    smsCursor.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Who told you "person" is the contact's display-name?

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.html#PERSON):

> PERSON
>
> The ID of the sender of the conversation, if present.

This is actually a "sender-id" this is never a contact-id, as an sms can be sent from a contact, a non-contact phone number, a non-phone-number (like `GOOGLE` or `FACEBOOK`) and from a group containing two or more of the above types.

If you'd like to get check if this is a contact, and if it is, get the contact's name, you need to pass two steps:

1. Use the canonical-address table to translate between id and phone-number (address). You can copy and use Android's helper class for this [`RecipientIdCache`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Mms/+/d00f7cd/src/com/android/mms/data/RecipientIdCache.java)
2. In case the address is a single phone number, use the `PHONE_LOOKUP` table to look for a contact with that number, this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7967182/819355

Comment: I tried no. 2 using the string of the address (even removing '+' from the number), but it the app still crashes.

Comment: what's the stack trace? what does it complain about?

Comment: also, print the address you get to log, to make sure you're using a valid input

Comment: It complains about `Cursor contactLookup` in `getContactDisplayNameByNumber` in my MainActivity.

Comment: can you post the full stack trace on www.pastebin.com ?

Comment: you don't have permission to read contacts... read this: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163953/android-runtime-permissions-how-to-implement

Comment: I've tried doing what it says from what I understand, but my MainActivity doesn't like more than one Cursor object created. Plus I already had permission to read contacts in my manifest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150061/discussion-between-marmor-and-spicyweenie).