# Disable ContentProvider by default and enable it programatically when needed

Tags: android, flutter

So i have a simple app and a content provider which looks like this :

```
    <provider
            android:name="org.kustom.api.Provider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.kustom.provider"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="false"
            tools:ignore="ExportedContentProvider">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="org.kustom.provider.WALLPAPERS"/>
            <action android:name="org.kustom.provider.WIDGETS"/>
            <action android:name="org.kustom.provider.KOMPONENTS"/>
            <action android:name="org.kustom.provider.LOCKSCREENS"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </provider>
```

I want to disable this by default and enable it when license checker succeeds.
I am using flutter so,I have already made a methodchannel which enables and disables content provider but it is not working.

Here's my methodchannel

```
package dev.dhanraj.kwgt.test.dashboard;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  private static final String CHANNEL = "dev.dhanraj.kwgt.test.dashboard";

  @Override
  public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
  super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);
    new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
        .setMethodCallHandler(
          (call, result) -> {
            // Note: this method is invoked on the main thread.
            if (call.method.equals("enable")) {
              ContextWrapper aContext = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
              aContext.getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(new android.content.ComponentName(aContext, "org.kustom.api.Provider"), android.content.pm.PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, 1);
              result.success(null);
              Toast.makeText(this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else{
              result.notImplemented();
            }
          }
        );
          }
  }
```

It makes a toast of done but doesn't affects ContentProvider as i can still see my assets in kwgt

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53658419

Comment: I think i have already tried something like this. You can check it out here and if you find a issue in there then please tell me- https://github.com/Not-Dhanraj/kwgt_test

Comment: If you need assistance with code you've written, you'll need to [edit] your question to add [mcve] of it here.

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: It looks like you might have the wrong constant: `COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED` should be `COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED`. They do have confusing names.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. just a small doubt, how can i disable it again if i need to

Comment: No problem. Yeah, that's what you would use `COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED` for. The key part is the last word in the name: `DISABLED`. It's the same code otherwise.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the quick reply and for helping me find the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Mike for figuring out the issue i was actually using `COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED` and this should have been `COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED` instead.